# Pulling CSV file from Azure Data Lake storage to on premise SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-lake

I have few CSV files located on Azure data lake storage which I am trying to import to my on premise SQL Server. Is it possible via regular BI tools like SSIS ?

I tried using the Azure connectors in the SSIS but for some reason I was not able to establish the connectivity. I have Spark/Scala code on the original parqueet files to generate the required CSVs. Mentioned about the Spark/Scala because I am also okay if there is any way to "push" data from Scala notebooks to on premise SQL server (I don't think this is possible)